# Setup proxy server on remote host using SSH?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, dedicated-server, proxy

I need to be able to browse the web with Firefox using the IP from my dedicated server.

Is there a way I could do this without having to use SSH on the local machine?

I mean, I want to setup the proxy server on the dedicated server, and then use it from any computer like a normal socks proxy without having to use ssh there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a very popular proxy server. You can use that but do not forget to configure ACL/Authentication to prevent abuse.